# error installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, ubuntu-mate, mate-terminal

I am trying to install scikit-learn on Ubuntu mate 16.10. For this I am following
[this guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

When I type `pip install -U scikit-learn` I get the following error message. Any idea? I have installed python-scipy, python-numpy etc.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 750, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 236, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question. What version of Python does scikit-learn support?

Comment: And this appears to be available in Debian as `python-sklearn`. So presumably in Ubuntu too. If it's available as a package for your distribution, use it.

Comment: thank you... It worked @FaheemMitha How do I know which version installed.

Comment: `apt-cache policy python-sklearn` or `dpkg -l python-sklearn`. The former will show all available versions, including the installed on, the latter only the installed version, along with its status. But it should also tell you what version it is installing when it's installing it.